# Retrieving data from Header to the parent's view

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates, swift-protocols

I have a custom `UICollectionViewController` with a custom header and cells.

I've implemented a protocol, in which the collectionView responds to, so in this way, I know in the collectionView when an object was accessed (button press for example) in the header class, so far so good.

What I want to do it that when I tap a button, in the `collectionView`, I need the header to retrieve some data that it owns to the `collectionView`

Lets say that I tap a save button in the `collectionView` and in order to execute a save , I need the current data from the header.

How can I achieve this?

Here's some of the current code:

```
    import UIKit

// collection view class
class EditUserProfileHeader: UICollectionViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    var delegate: CustomHeaderDelegate?

    //(... some default code ...)
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath) as! CustomHeader
        header.delegate = self
        return header
    }

    // header delegate conform
    func didTapPhoto() {
        // this fires everytime the button is pressed inside the header
        print("didTapPhoto was tapped inside the header")
    }


    func didTapSave() {
        //here I need the header's data from it's labels and so on
    }

}


protocol CustomHeaderDelegate {
    func didTapPhoto()
}



class CustomHeader: UICollectionViewCell { 
    var delegate: CustomHeaderDelegate?
    //(... some class regular code ...)

    func didTapPhoto() {
        delegate?.didTapPhoto() // here I pass to the collectionView that this button was pressed in the header
    }

}
```

As you can see, I've implemented a delegate to whenever the `didTapButton` occurs in the header, I call the delegate function so I know in the `collectionView` that the button fired.

Now I need to try the opposite; when I tap a button inside the `collectionView` I need the header to know it and that it retrieves the desired data.

Can anyone give me a hand on this?

I tried to implement another protocol to do the opposite but I might done it wrong because it didn't work, mostly because I couldn't 'say' in the header class that the parent's delegate conformed to that specific delegate, has I did in the `collectionView` when I instantiated the header object and set its `delegate to self`

Thanks

Comment: mark the question as resolved/solved if it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to access the desired header inserting the following line in the didTapSave() function

```
let header = collectionView?.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)) as? CustomHeader
```

As that I can access the header updated data.